# Printing elements of an Array in C

Tags: c, arrays, enums

Well, it is a basic program which I got an array of chars, like :

`char alphabet[5] = {'A', 'B2', 'C', 'D4', 'E'};`

and I want to print elements of that array, inside of a for-loop :

`int remainder = my_number % 5;
 printf("%c\n", alphabet[remainder]);`

thats it's where I can't make it run as expected the print out comes 
`A`, `2`, `C`, `4` or `E`. How I can make it print `B2` and `D4` ?

I've heard about using enums but I din't understand how I could use, I get confuse on the idea of elements have value and how I could get the elements out using they value, e.g: `enum letters {'a', 'b', 'c'};` a = 0, b = 1 and c = 2.

(maybe just my syntax it's not correct, but please if you can help me ...)

I'll open my code for easier explanation.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

const char *notes[13] = {"C", "C2", "D", "D2", "E", "F", "F2", "G", "G2", "A", "A2", "B", "c"}; // The 2's is for the "#"

int main(int argc, char const *argv[]) // Just using argv[1] to say how much numbers I want to print 
{
  int now, before_1 = 1, before_2 = 1, rem, steps; // "rem" stands for remainder
  char note;

  if (atoi(argv[1]) <= 2)
    for (steps = 0; steps < atoi(argv[1]); steps++)
      printf("1\n");
  else
    for (steps = 0; steps < atoi(argv[1]); steps++) // Main loop for Fibonacci's Numbers
    {
      now = before_1 + before_2;
      rem = now % 13;
      note = notes[rem];
      printf("Note : %c <=> Rem : %d. Num : %d\n", note, rem, now);

      before_2 = before_1; // Change values of variables
      before_1 = now;
    }

  return 0;
}
```

The idea is get the numbers of Fibonacci's Serie and transform them into all 13 notes possible (include the sharp ones), but as I've said the output is note going too good.

Comment: `B2` and `D4` are not chars.

Comment: Are they strings ?

Comment: @tkausl: They are valid character constants. Just likely not correct as initialiser for a `char` object.

Comment: But in that case it should have printed just the `B ` and `D` because are really chars , right ? @tkausl @Olaf

Comment: It is not clear what you want. 1) An alphabet is normally single letters, so what is the reason you want to  have two characters in some entries? 2) `enums`s are something very different. 3) `char` typically takes **one** character. It is definitively not a "string". 4) If you want a "string", use a C-string. 5) C does not have a string _type_. It is all convention on how to use `char` arrays. 6) An array is not the same as a pointer! 7) All this will be explained in any good C book.

Comment: And enable compiler warnings and pay heed to them. Actually the compiler should generate conversion/truncation warnings. Maybe you have to add `-Wconversion` (gcc) or whatever your compiler uses.

Answer (score 3):

In the original version of this question, the problem is twofold.

First, *alphabet* is defined as an array of characters, i.e. `char alphabet[]`. According to the initial question, it should rather be declared as an array of strings, i.e. `char *alphabet[]`.

Second, which in some way follows from the first issue, the initialization values are characters, whereas they should be defined as strings. The definition of *F2* as a character, hence `'F2'`, will not represent a literal string *"F2"*.

```
char *alphabet[] = {"A", "B2", "C", "D4", "E"};
```

Finally, in order to print strings rather than characters, the *printf* format identifier has to be changed from **%c** to **%s**.

Summing up, you can print the elements of a string array as follows:

```
char *alphabet[5] = {"A", "B2", "C", "D4", "E"};
for(int i = 0; i < 5; i++){
    printf("%s} ", alphabet[i]);
}
```

If you don't know the size of the array from the beginning, you can also write:

```
char *alphabet[] = {"A", "B2", "C", "D4", "E"};
for(int i = 0; i < sizeof(alphabet)/sizeof(alphabet[0]); i++){
    printf("%s ", alphabet[i]);
}
```

Hope it helps!

Comment: You should elaborate what OPs fault is. However, apparently OP change the game completely.

Comment: Well, you added quite some explanation, that's good. Some additions/corrections: _character constants (e.g. `'a'`) are of type `int`, not `char`. C does not have a character type in the sense of other languages. `char` is an integer in the first place. Also note OP changed the question, maybe you want to add what is wrong with the _actual__ code (the late change is very bad style). That's why you should alsoways ask for a [mcve], such snippets often lack relevant context and/or are not the code beining compiled.

Comment: Yes, I agree with you. However, I did not address the coding style as I wanted to stick with the question. He is not asking for a style review and perhaps it would turn the main focus on the different ways to implement a variation of the Fibonacci series.

Comment: That is not about the coding style, but about [ask]. Maybe attitude is a better term (sorry, ESL). An answer should be complete and also cover aspects not explicitly asked for if they are obvious. Visual style only if it relates to the problem (e.g. missing brace)

Answer (score 1):

`char` is used for single characters. If you want multiple characters you need to use strings.

```
char *strings[] = { "A", "B2", "C", "D4", "E"};

int remainder = my_number % 5;
printf("%s\n", strings[remainder]);
```

Answer (score -1):

Single quotes are used to indicate a char. So `'B2'` would be treated a char. Instead you want `char*`, and thus double quotes.

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/115475/discussion-on-answer-by-odin19-printing-elements-of-an-array-in-c).

Answer (score -1):

As odin19 pointed out, B2 and D4 are not characters in C. In order to print them you can use double quotes in the elements of the array and print them as strings using %s in your printf.